# What is correct: It's just not so easy or it just is not so easy?

Tags: grammar

"Life is simple **it's** just **not** so easy" or 
"Life is simple **it** just **is not** so easy"

I would like to know if there's a correct way to say that or in case of both are right so what is the difference? 
It's just not or it just is not ?

Answer (score 2):

This one: "Life is simple it's just not so easy"
Though I would recast the sentence to: "Life is simple: It's just not so easy"
Of course, you can write "Life is simple; it's just not so easy" but those are two conflicting ideas.

"just" normally goes after the "be verb."